# Could not set unknown property 'debugSymbolLevel' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-ndk

Received this error

> Could not set unknown property 'debugSymbolLevel' for object of type
> com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions.

when I ran `flutter build appbundle` into the terminal. I'm new to Android Studio and using the Flutter Sdk, and I don't really know what to do. If you've run into similar problems, it'd be helpful if you put down what worked for you, thanks!

Comment: I came across this because I am trying to use this same option. The android docs explain this option here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#native-crash-support.

Did you figure this out? I am curious. At the very least you could look into flutter and see if there is an open issue about this.

Comment: From the output error you shared, you are not writting the property and value correctly. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63373245/how-to-add-debug-symbols-to-build-gradle