# How to add native debug symbols to Android bundle file?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

I have my Android Studio project and when I upload a bundle (.aab) file to Google Play Console I get this warning:

> This App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug
> symbols. We recommend you upload a symbol file to make your crashes
> and ANRs easier to analyze and debug. [Learn More](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#native-crash-support)

I tapped on the Lean More option and I basically states this:

> If your project builds an Android App Bundle, you can automatically
> include the native debug symbols file in it. To include this file in
> release builds, add the following to your app's build.gradle file:
>
> android.buildTypes.release.ndk.debugSymbolLevel = { SYMBOL_TABLE |
> FULL }

To add the debugSymbolLevel keyword I followed instructions here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63436935/1363087
But my aab file is still not getting the native debug symbols file in it. The size of the output file is the same and Google Play keeps telling me the error message above.

Any help of what I am doing wrong?

Searching for help about this issue, I see there are many pages that talks about "flutter". It is the first time I hear about "flutter". I don't know what it is. I am using this:
Android Studio: version 4.1.1
Android Gradle plugin version: 4.1.3
Gradle version: 6.5

Thanks and I hope someone could point me somewhere.

Comment: Same to me here. Don't know why.

Comment: you can add it manually. please refer to this answer, I always go through these steps:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68778908/8898138