# Problem related to adding ndk to build.gradle

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have created android build of my Flutter application.

Then I created an internal testing release. It is showing a warning

```
This App Bundle contains native code, and you haven't imported any debugging symbols. We recommend importing a symbol file to help analyze and debug crashes and ANR errors.
```

I installed Cmake and Ndk and add this to `build.gradle`

```
  ndkVersion <ndkVersion>
    ndk {
      debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
    }
```

But I get this error while generating the APK:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Unknown DebugSymbolLevel value 'build_c14d3u5oz2rfmrc26tqvdpxjy$_run_closure4$_closure15@71307b15'. Possible values are 'full', 'symbol_table', 'none'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: You need to add this block under the buildTypes sections. Same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63436935/2649154

Comment: if you had the message regarding `This App Bundle contains native code`  **before** you added the ndk, remove it, it's not going to fix anything. Would assume you use a library like a barcodescanner that comes with native code. Ignore the message you don't need to debug that library