# Flutter "The native debug symbols contain an invalid directory __MACOSX" when uploading debug symbols to Google Play Console

Tags: flutter, macos, google-play-console

I'm trying to upload my bundle Flutter app to Google Play from my Mac, but I'm getting a warning about adding "debug symbols":

> This App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols. We recommend you upload a symbol file to make your crashes and ANRs easier to analyze and debug.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68778908/12695188), I need to zip the three folders and upload it as a "debug symbols".

However, I'm getting the above error when trying to upload the compressed files:

> The native debug symbols contain an invalid directory __MACOSX. Only Android ABIs are supported.

What is the problem? What should I do?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have solved the issue by deleting all `__MACOSX` folders from my zip.

After compressing your `arm64-v8a`, `armeabi-v7a` and `x86_64` folders, run the above command to get rid of the Mac `__MACOSX` files:

```
zip -d Archive.zip "__MACOSX*"
```

Then you can upload the .zip symbol file to Google Play Console.

Comment: This worked for me. I'm using Gradle 8.2 in my Flutter 3 project and I've tried all solutions from internet to automate a script in build.gradle and to avoid to do this task manually. But there is no solution for the moment and the old script is not working anymore. I mean this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63373245/how-to-add-debug-symbols-to-build-gradle

Comment: To perform that command, point your terminal to the projects lib folder [ProjectName/build/app/intermediats/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib]

Answer (score 0):

When you compress folders using MacOS Archive utility than it will include _MACOSX file as well, so there are two ways to handle the situation:

1- Delete _MACOSX folder that is hidden.

2- Download WinZip and Compress using it.