# The native debug symbols contain an invalid directory debug-symbols. Only Android ABIs are supported

Tags: android, flutter

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62568757/playstore-error-app-bundle-contains-native-code-and-youve-not-uploaded-debug/68778908#68778908), I need to zip the three folders and upload it as a "debug symbols".

And then I encounter this problems:
`The native debug symbols contain an invalid directory __MACOSX. Only Android ABIs are supported.`

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76621112/22674672) which is used to work but now it doesn't work anymore.

Now Google Console yell at me this message:

`The native debug symbols contain an invalid directory debug-symbols. Only Android ABIs are supported.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem too,

The solution is pretty simple, you just need to compress your arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a and x86_64 folders by this [tool](https://www.ezyzip.com/zip-folder-online.html#).

Note: Remember to remove `.DS_Store` file:
[image]