# Warning from Google Play Console (This App Bundle contains native code....) (Android / App Bundle file)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

> This App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug
> symbols. We recommend you upload a symbol file to make your crashes
> and ANRs easier to analyze and debug.

I am trying to resolve this issue, so I already added

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ndk.debugSymbolLevel = "FULL"
    }
```

But I still see this warning, so I try to add debugSymbolLevel in this way:

```
buildTypes {
        getByName("debug") {
            ...
            ...
            ...
        }

        getByName("release") {
            ...
            ...
            ...
            ndk {
                debugSymbolLevel = "full"
            }
        }
    }
```

And again, I still see this warning, so I can't understand how can I fix this issue. Please, could you provide more info to resolve it.

Thanks a lot :)

By the way:

- Gradle plugin -> "8.1.1"
- Gradle version -> "8.0.*"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add debug symbols to build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63373245/how-to-add-debug-symbols-to-build-gradle)

Comment: No :( I already try this answers, but they don't help me